# The form code does not work in firefox (submit and alert)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, firefox

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#submitButton").click(function () {
    $.post($("#payment").attr("action"), $("#payment").serialize(),
           function () {
      alert('Form 1 submitted');
    });

    $.post($("#normal").attr("action"), $("#normal").serialize(),
           function () {
      alert('Form 1 submitted');
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="normal" action="send.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="text" name="fio" placeholder="  (Имя получателя)" id="q" required="required"/><br>
  <input type="text" name="country" placeholder="" id="w" required="required"/><br>
  <input type="text" name="street" placeholder="  улица, дом, квартира" id="e" required="required"/><br>
  <input type="text" name="bl" placeholder="  Квартира, блок и т.п. (при необходимости)" id="o"/><br>
  <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="" id="r" required="required"/><br>
  <input type="text" name="region" placeholder="" id="t" required="required"/><br>
  <input type="number" name="index" placeholder="" id="y" required="required"/><br>
  <input type="number" name="mobnumber" placeholder="  В международном формате" id="u" required="required"/><br></form>

<form id="payment" name="payment" method="post"    action="https://sci.interkassa.com/" enctype="utf-8">
  <input type="hidden" name="ik_co_id" value="58515c6a3c1eafd5708b4569" />
  <input type="hidden" name="ik_pm_no" value="ID_4233" />
  <input type="hidden" name="ik_am" value="382" />
  <input type="hidden" name="ik_cur" value="UAH" />
  <input type="hidden" name="ik_desc" value="Event Description" />
  <input type="hidden" name="ik_act" value="payways" />
  <input type="hidden" name="ik_pw_off" value="yandexmoney" />
  <input type="hidden" name="ik_suc_u" value="https://www.yandex.ua/" />
  <input type="hidden" name="ik_fal_u" value="https://www.yandex.ua/" />
  <input type="hidden" name="ik_pnd_u" value="https://www.yandex.ua/" />
  <input type="hidden" name="ik_exp" value="2016-12-15" />
  <input type="hidden" name="ik_ltm" value="3600" />
  <input type="hidden" name="ik_loc" value="ru" />
  <input type="hidden" name="ik_enc" value="utf-8" />
  <input type="hidden" name="ik_int" value="web" />
  <input type="hidden" name="ik_am_t" value="payway" />
  <input type="submit" id="submitButton" value="ОПЛАТИТЬ" id="sub"/></form>
```

This code works on all browsers except Firefox (forms sent successfully, the redirect works, the site asks for confirmation alert). But firefox immediately redirecting to the site without  send forms and confirm the alert. Help please, i dont found answer in ru internet. HELP ME PLEASE.
P.S. Sorry for my english, I use GOOGLE translator, but I try to make the text readable. thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You've to change the type of input `submit` to `button` since you're sending the data using ajax request from the code :

```
<input type="button" id="submitButton" value="ОПЛАТИТЬ" id="sub"/></form>
```

Or you could use `e.preventDefault()` or `return false` to prevent submission like :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#submitButton").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.post($("#payment").attr("action"), $("#payment").serialize(),
          function () {
              alert('Form 1 submitted');
          });

        $.post($("#normal").attr("action"), $("#normal").serialize(),
          function () {
              alert('Form 1 submitted');
          });
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You don't need both `preventDefault()` and `return false;`. They do the same thing, so just pick one.

Answer (score 0):

The submit button inside the form will trigger its action. Try putting it outside the form.

```
<form id="payment" name="payment" method="post"    action="https://sci.interkassa.com/" enctype="utf-8">
...
<input type="hidden" name="ik_am_t" value="payway" />
</form>

<input type="submit" id="submitButton" value="ОПЛАТИТЬ" id="sub"/>
```